# jQuery - Keep original html content and retrieve it, even if overwritten

Tags: jquery, html, overwrite

I have some content in the `numbers` div. When I click `numbers-clicker`, the content of numbers `123456789` is saved to the oldNumbers variable, the content is changed to `987654321`, and the class `opened` is toggled on the `numbers` div. When I click `numbers-clicker` again, I am trying to restore the original oldNumbers, so `123456789` to the `numbers` div, instead, the oldNumbers is overwritten with the `987654321`. How can we make sure the oldNumbers stays as the beginning content of the `numbers` div, `123456789`?

```
<div id="numbers-clicker">Clicker</div>
<div id="numbers">123456789</div>

$('#numbers-clicker').off('click').on('click',function(){
    $this = $(this);
    var oldNumbers = $('#numbers').html();

    if(!$this.is('.opened')){ 
        $('#numbers').html('987654321'); 
    } else { 
        $('#numbers').html(oldNumbers); 
    }
    $this.toggleClass('opened')
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5tnuj/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to declare `oldNumbers` outside of your callback:

```
var oldNumbers = $('#numbers').html();
$('#numbers-clicker').off(...);
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can store the old value as a attribute of the tag with

```
 $('#numbers').attr('data-old-numbers', oldNumbers )
```

and retreive it with

```
 $('#numbers').attr('data-old-numbers')
```

Comment: @Wonka This answer works, you just aren't implementing it correctly. Most likely you are making the same mistake as the one in your question.

Comment: It does work, you can store any arbitrary piece of information on the DOM using data-* attributes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#numbers-clicker').data('txt', $('#numbers').text()).on('click', function() {
    $('#numbers').html($(this).is('.opened') ? '987654321' : $(this).data('txt'));
    $(this).toggleClass('opened')
});
​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5tnuj/1/)